# Fill below two functions.

Tags: plotting, filling

I'm new to Mathematica and some of the filling stuff is confusing me. I don't think this should be too hard but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have plotted x and -x. I want to fill below BOTH of them and above BOTH of them in two different plots. How can this be done?

Comment: Please always try post _some_ code. Did you manage to Plot the functions?: -Post it-. Do you have some filling code not working?: -Post it too- That way you get your question out of the dangerous "do it for me" zone

Comment: @Kuba The folks aren't usually in danger since they tend to be farther than a frog's leap from a certain mod. But the questions are ... poor questions!

Comment: @belisarius I have to disagree with you here.  Adding code that doesn't work improves nothing in this case.  Instead we need(ed) a graphic example of what was desired, even if it meant drawing it by hand and taking a photo.  *That* would be effort and information that was not pointless.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok. We disagree. I guess that's becoming an standard :)

Comment: @belisarius Please remind me (sincerely), on what other issues have we disagreed recently?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The real strength of this site is based upon sharing, healthy collaboration and some humor. We're not going to be bold about a few minor disagreements like this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about `Filling`, but what about something like

```
Show[
  RegionPlot[Abs[y] > Abs[x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Frame -> False],
  Plot[{-x, x}, {x, -2, 2}],
  Axes -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nevermind I answered it myself with your hint. Thanks alot.

Comment: @TheNumber23 Would you please add your solution to your question?  I'm still not certain what you want.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I did the exact same thing as you. But in I plotted Abs[y]>Abs[x]&&y<0.

Comment: @TheNumber23 I'm not RiemannZeta, but thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments above I think you want this:

```
Plot[{-x, x}, {x, -2, 2},
  Filling -> {1 -> Bottom, 2 -> {{1}, White}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I want. I tried pretty much every combination of that except the one that works. Thanks.